# ASP.NET Core MVC EF: Sequence contains no elements with FromSqlRaw executing a query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I am doing an Application in ASP.NET Core MVC 6.

I am using EF and run the select using `FromSqlRaw`

I have a Generic method

```
public async Task<T?> ExecuteGenericRow(Query query)
{
    var cParameters = new SqlParameter[query.Parameters?.Count ?? 0];
    return await _dbContext.Set<T>().FromSqlRaw(query, cParameters).FirstAsync();
}
```

I call it

```
 UserClientResultModel? result = await ExecuteGenericRow(queryDataByClientUserId);
```

My Method is like this

```
 public class SubsidyResultModel 
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("ParticipantId")]
        public int  ParticipantId { get;  set; }
        [Column("StartDate")]
        public string? StartDate { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        [Column("EndDate")]
        public string? EndDate { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }



public class CobraDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public CobraDbContext(DbContextOptions<CobraDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<SubsidyResultModel> ParticipantISubsidy{ get; set; } = null!;
      
        // This method may not be needed. Please remove at the later stage
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
           
        }
    }
```

When the Query in `query`, returns a record.. it works fine, but when it returns NO records, throws

```
Error:Internal Server Error
Sequence contains no elements
```

My idea is to get and empty model as result.

What I am missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check out the docs for [`FirstAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.firstasync?view=efcore-7.0), the exceptions part:

> `InvalidOperationException`
> No element satisfies the condition in predicate
> -or -
> source contains no elements.

So it will throw if your query yielded no results.

Since you are already returning `T?` - use `FirstOrDefault`:

```cs
return await _dbContext.Set<T>()
    .FromSqlRaw(query, cParameters)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

I replaced

```
 return await _dbContext.Set<T>().FromSqlRaw(query, cParameters).FirstAsync();
```

with

```
return await _dbContext.Set<T>().FromSqlRaw(query).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```